# frequency counter in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects.

Objects looks like this:

```
0: Object
_id: "555baa9a034de05173e9fee4"
name: "Smirnoff Vodka"
number: 120
priceQuantity: 195
subtotal: 195
taxes: Array[0]
```

Now, from all the objects, I have to calculate sum of amount of total sale of every time so that I know the total sale amount of every item. .

i.e push the values in these arrays

```
itemAmount=[];
itemName=[];
```

The array is going to be very large therefore I need it to be very efficient at the same time.

Also, before the total amount is calculated, I have to iterate over the taxes array so that to add all the taxes. What could be the efficient way to do it?

Comment: What inefficient way have you found?

Comment: Define "very large".

Comment: what toal sale is it price

Comment: Having two arrays for name and amount doesn't make much sense to me either. Don't you want those two pieces of information linked?

Comment: @aduch: I tried iterating over the whole array , adding elements that have not been added into a new array and then checking with nested loop if the element already exists, incrementing count. But that is not e going to be very efficient. I can show the code if you would like me to.But I am looking for something more efficient.

Comment: @SimranKaur I think showing your code is still a good idea. Even though it seems not satisfactory to you, you might be surprised

Comment: Does your current project use a database or is that an API response? If it IS a database, you can easily get the sum from a query.

Comment: It's an API response.

Comment: @Andy: No, The data is to be fed to charts API.

Comment: if it's an API response it probably have no reasons to be "very large". It may be as big as you want, but it's probably not big enough to stop allowing you to work on it. In a nutshell: can you please provide us your code? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var itemAmount = [], itemName = [];

myArray.map(function(obj){
  var total = obj.subtotal;
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.taxes.length; i++) {
      total += obj.taxes[i];
  }

  var index = itemName.indexOf(obj.name);
  if (index === -1) {
    itemAmount.push(total);
    itemName.push(obj.name);
  } else {
    itemAmount[index] += total;
  }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0d809ge9/1/)

Comment: Oh, That did not help. It is pushing elements with repeating elements over again . I do not want that.

Comment: if the prices of any products change, the calculated totals will be wrong.

Comment: @Pjetr Why would we recalculate the totals if the price of the products are changing.. The amount of money which the company earned was calculated at the previous price, before the price changes.. If you recalculate the totals then, for sure, you will have wrong data about what you sale at what price..

Comment: @MateiMihai, because of the nature of Javascript which calculates at runtime, using the values it has at the present. So unless you save this data somewhere, you'll recalculate this every time you run the application.
And if you store the values, why would you need to calculate this? Just every time you sell an item you should update the stored value, using the current price. If it's simply to store a value with the current data, because this is a new feature, there are better ways to calculate the value without using JS. That's why I make the assumption that OP will always recalculate it…

Answer (score 0):

If you need these values every time you open your application, it might be a good idea to not calculate these values, but to store them in your database.
For every purchase, just adjust the totalSale value with the current price, and update totalSaleVAT with current price and VAT.

In addition to being a lot easier, doing it this way will give no false data when the prices change. Because the sold values won't be affected when the price rises or falls.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use the good things of javascript like dinamic allocation but the bad ones?

I would set an object for the products:

```
var Products = {}
```

And then set the entries like:

```
if(!products[WHATEVER])
  products[WHATEVER] = [];

var temp = {};
temp.name = "asdf";
temp....

products[WHATEVER].push(temp);
```

so you have one products object where you can access just using id, name or whatever you want to any product, which is an array of the product entries.

Try it